# Is it possible to update a boolean field within a data extension when an email is sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm trying to update a boolean field in the sending data extension from false to true when an email is sent to a subscriber. Could I use AMPscript to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the AMPscript function `UpdateDE(1,2,3,4,5,6)`. You can find the full documentation including an example in the [marketing cloud documentation on UpdateDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatede.htm)

**Example:**

```
UpdateDE("YourDataExtension",1,"_SubscriberKey",_SubscriberKey,"YourBoolean", "True")
```